# Passing numpy arrays in a jit function

Tags: python, numba

I'm trying to use `Numba` to accelerate some calculations. I do so I've had to rewrite some code since some `NumPy` functions are not supported in `Numba` for example, `numpy.loadtxt()`. my workaround is to create a non jitted function that opens the file, and then pass the `NumPy` array into the jitted function, but I've noticed when I pass the array into the jit function the values of the array are all 0.

I'm not sure if this is due to the values being very small for example, orders of `e-20` or the `@njit` decorator don't support `NumPy` arrays when passing it in the function.

Here's my code. I've read about `@vectorize`, but I'm not sure if this would solve my issue. Is my only option is to open the file in a pythonic way?

Here's a portion of the PMF file.

```
85  1.52012647452268E-05    0   
86  3.04025294904536E-05    0   
87  1.52012647452268E-05    0   
88  3.04025294904536E-05    0   
89  0.000258421500669   0   
90  0.000228018971178   2.88879580546849E-05    
91  0.000273622765414   0   
92  0.000547245530828   0.000101107853191   
93  0.000820868296242   2.88879580546849E-05
94  0.001276906238599   0.000129995811246
```

```
import numpy as np
import math as ma

from numba import jit, njit, vectorize, objmode

a = 'C:/Users/Luis/Desktop/DM/MADHAT-master/Input/Set4.dat'
FILE_PATH = 'C:/Users/Luis/Desktop/DM/MADHAT-master'

gal = 58
@njit
def fun1(INPUT,NOBS, PMF):
    print(PMF) ## entire matrix is replaced with values of 0 ex 0, 0.00000000e+00
    ## The only time it's not replaced with zero is when i loop trough specific columns
    ## This goes the same for INPUT and NOBS

    return 0
#print(fun1(func(a)))


def func(INPUT):

    dat_file = np.loadtxt(INPUT)
    NOBS = FILE_PATH + '/PMFdata/Fermi_Pass8R3_239557417_585481831/NOBS.dat'
    PMF_data = FILE_PATH + '/PMFdata/Fermi_Pass8R3_239557417_585481831/pmf.dat'
    dwarf_list = [int(i) for i in dat_file[:, 0]]
    #(dwarf_list)
    obs_data = np.loadtxt(NOBS)
    PMF = np.loadtxt(PMF_data)
    dwarf_count = len(dat_file)
    dwarf_data = dat_file

    print(fun1(dat_file,obs_data,PMF))
    return 0
print(func(a))
```

Comment: Can you do a [*minimal reproducible* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It would help us to better understand/track the problem (especially since the code is quite big).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. This is much better (because of the size), but still not great for *reproducibility*. Can you provide the loaded input files or just put a small example of input that cause the issue in the code itself? (the second one is better for future readers).

Comment: Added a small portion of the file

Comment: Is is better if you specify the array type like `np.loadtxt(PMF_data, dtype=np.float64)`? I guess the variable amount of space and the presence of final spaces some times does not help Numpy at all. I think it would be better to use a CVS like input. If you cannot modify the input, then maybe using `read_table` of Pandas could be better (since Pandas have a more advanced text file parser -- note that parameters needs to be probably tweaked)